# Bootstrap and html5 - section or div?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I have a question regarding using Bootstrap - I see that on default they use a lot of DIVs instead of sections etc.

I've been reading the HTML5 specification lately - when to use section and when to use div. The basic idea is that DIVs should be used only if any specific HTML5 element doesn't apply.

Now, if I want to create an HTML5 website using Bootstrap, should I change the DIVs to specific HTML elements (for example SECTION)?

Comment: No need to do this really. By all means use the newer HTML5 elements if you wish to do so but it's not required. I tend to use HEADER and FOOTER and a few other misc. HTML5 elements but as I've said it's not absolutely necessary.

Comment: HTML5 is focused on semantic. If you need an element for a specific use that is covered by an html5 element, you should use this to upgrade the semantic of your page for accessibility reader or robots. But through this recommandation, each developper can choose to use the element he wants. Bootstrap use divs because it's a general element that can be applied in the most cases for containers. But the same examples can be done with span, section,...

Answer (score 45, accepted):

It really depends on your page's content but basically you could use HTML5 tags and apply bootstrap classes like this:

```
<section class="row">
    ...
</section>

<footer class="row">
    ...
</footer>
```

But as said it depends on your content, and even more, you're not forced to use `<section>` tags, they have the specific purpose to represents a generic document or application section, and they're not mandatory.

The `<div>` tags are generic tag usually used for styling, as in bootstrap. But if you want  to keep the `<section>` tags, maybe you could prefer a mixed solution like this:

```
<section>
    <div class="row">
       ...
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      ...
    </div>
</section>
```

With this solution the `<section>` tag is used for grouping contents, as it should be, and the `<div>` tags for styling it.

Comment: I'm always confused by sections, to the point where I wonder what the point actually is if it can't be easily inferred, and so many people (like me) don't use them correctly, or maybe don't use them correctly.  I understand it isn't for layout, but would you ever use the section tag to wrap like this?  It's like I feel the need to use section tags so I attempt to do so, but I really don't understand them.  I might actually wrap using sections like you do above, but do I really want to?

Comment: Note that a row must always be contained within a <div class="container"> and not directly in a section.

Answer (score 24):

`Section` is not for design purpose, it has specific meaning. It indicates separate sections/parts of a web page. On the other hand, `div` has no specific meaning. You can use `div`s anonymously for managing your front-end styles.

Comment: And div's can be used inside sections. Sections are to demarcate the actual content meaning, rather than to help with styling.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I've read using section is correct semantics and helps with SEO.

Answer (score 1):

Section tags are used to segment your web pages and makes it SEO optimized while divs are used for styling your contents.