# bootstrap para margin spacing

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I just started bootstrap and I had an issue which I am not able to resolve
when I give `margin` to my `section` in code the third section comes down although I have given width to be `col-md-4` I'm not able to give margin in order to separate the sections also there is one small issue when the `browserwidth` goes less than `768px` the section stack (which I want) but a scroll bar to view from left to right also comes which I don't won't can you please help me and sorry for posting code like this I'm new to stackoverflow.

```css
    body {
     background: #F13421;
     font-size: 16px;
     margin: 0;
    }
    
    #header-nav {
     border-radius: 0;
    }
    .container {
     border: none;
     margin-left: auto;
     margin-right: auto;
     margin-top: 10px;
     margin-bottom: 0;
    
     padding: 10px 10px 0 10px;
    
    }
    
    
    .navbar-brand h1 {
       font-size: 2em;
       margin-top: -5px;
       margin-bottom: 40px;
       line-height: 0.65;
    }
    
    #nav-list {
     margin-top: 0;
     margin-bottom: 0;
     background: #F1F021;
    }
    
    #nav-list hr {
    
    width: 90%;
    }
    .row {
     margin: 10px;
    }
    #tiles section {
     background: #D3D3D3 ;
        margin: 5px;
        
    }
```

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
     
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
     
     <title>Module 3 Solution</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <header>
         <nav id="header-nav" class="navbar navbar-default">
          <div class="container">
           <div class="navbar-header">
            <div class="navbar-brand"><h1>Food, LLC</h1>
    
            </div>
           
               <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapsable-nav" aria-expanded="false">
                        
                          <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                          <span class="icon-bar"></span>        
            
               </button>
                    </div>
    
                    <div id="collapsable-nav" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
                     <ul id="nav-list" class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right visible-xs">
                      <li class="text-center">
                       <a href="#chicken"><div>Chicken</div></a>
                       <hr class="visible-xs">
                      </li>
                      <li class="text-center">
                       <a href="#beef">Beef</a>
                       <hr class="visible-xs">
                      </li>
                      <li  class="text-center">
                       <a href="#sushi">Sushi</a>
                      </li>
                      
                     </ul>
                    </div>
    
          </div><!--END OF CONTAINER-->
         </nav><!--END OF NAV-->
        </header><!--END OF HEADER-->
        <div id="main-content" class="container-fluid">
         <h2 class="text-center">Our Menu</h2>
         <div id="tiles" class="row">
          <section id="chicken" class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
           <h3>Chicken</h3>
           <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Repellendus dignissimos aut quasi quibusdam aspernatur possimus officia nulla consectetur velit! At, asperiores dolorem. Et iure assumenda, repudiandae laudantium, voluptatibus ex dignissimos, eum quaerat ducimus cupiditate corporis totam. Illo, alias voluptatem accusamus ut natus consequuntur quis laboriosam doloribus porro vero assumenda quo temporibus quos quam quisquam, libero quod, itaque eius sit ducimus totam iste possimus architecto debitis? Commodi ut minima maiores consequuntur voluptates unde deleniti error vero tempora, eligendi blanditiis, deserunt aliquam nobis porro dolores tenetur amet eius! Aspernatur, vitae. Suscipit, dolores quos doloribus. Velit repudiandae provident a, in ad id aspernatur dolor ratione eos placeat, ex temporibus ipsum eligendi sequi reprehenderit cupiditate perferendis eaque, explicabo blanditiis nemo dolorem aperiam minima deleniti. Tempore, rem, quam? Totam non reiciendis amet, at reprehenderit inventore, adipisci nesciunt itaque dolorum asperiores, ducimus corrupti quam impedit quaerat autem quod officia tempora. Itaque dicta deleniti fugit, laudantium rerum sint consectetur asperiores, quia veritatis dignissimos esse in nesciunt distinctio facere iure facilis voluptatibus placeat voluptate voluptatum expedita animi a veniam nulla ea. Enim aliquid, non. Necessitatibus nam fugiat autem quae qui quam consequatur repudiandae quidem ipsam impedit distinctio, sequi doloribus, quaerat quod ab maxime. Harum facilis sed commodi reprehenderit? <div>(End of Chicken Section) <a href="#chicken"><span>Back to Top</span></a></div></p>
           
          </section>
          <section id="beef" class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 ">
           <h3>Beef</h3>
           <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Repellendus dignissimos aut quasi quibusdam aspernatur possimus officia nulla consectetur velit! At, asperiores dolorem. Et iure assumenda, repudiandae laudantium, voluptatibus ex dignissimos, eum quaerat ducimus cupiditate corporis totam. Illo, alias voluptatem accusamus ut natus consequuntur quis laboriosam doloribus porro vero assumenda quo temporibus quos quam quisquam, libero quod, itaque eius sit ducimus totam iste possimus architecto debitis? Commodi ut minima maiores consequuntur voluptates unde deleniti error vero tempora, eligendi blanditiis, deserunt aliquam nobis porro dolores tenetur amet eius! Aspernatur, vitae. Suscipit, dolores quos doloribus. Velit repudiandae provident a, in ad id aspernatur dolor ratione eos placeat, ex temporibus ipsum eligendi sequi reprehenderit cupiditate perferendis eaque, explicabo blanditiis nemo dolorem aperiam minima deleniti. Tempore, rem, quam? Totam non reiciendis amet, at reprehenderit inventore, adipisci nesciunt itaque dolorum asperiores, ducimus corrupti quam impedit quaerat autem quod officia tempora. Itaque dicta deleniti fugit, laudantium rerum sint consectetur asperiores, quia veritatis dignissimos esse in nesciunt distinctio facere iure facilis voluptatibus placeat voluptate voluptatum expedita animi a veniam nulla ea. Enim aliquid, non. Necessitatibus nam fugiat autem quae qui quam consequatur repudiandae quidem ipsam impedit distinctio, sequi doloribus, quaerat quod ab maxime. Harum facilis sed commodi reprehenderit?<div>(End of Beef Section) <a href="#beef"><span>Back to Top</span></a></div></p>
           
          </section>
          <section id="sushi" class="col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
           <h3>Sushi</h3>
           <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Repellendus dignissimos aut quasi quibusdam aspernatur possimus officia nulla consectetur velit! At, asperiores dolorem. Et iure assumenda, repudiandae laudantium, voluptatibus ex dignissimos, eum quaerat ducimus cupiditate corporis totam. Illo, alias voluptatem accusamus ut natus consequuntur quis laboriosam doloribus porro vero assumenda quo temporibus quos quam quisquam, libero quod, itaque eius sit ducimus totam iste possimus architecto debitis? Commodi ut minima maiores consequuntur voluptates unde deleniti error vero tempora, eligendi blanditiis, deserunt aliquam nobis porro dolores tenetur amet eius! Aspernatur, vitae. Suscipit, dolores quos doloribus. Velit repudiandae provident a, in ad id aspernatur dolor ratione eos placeat, ex temporibus ipsum eligendi sequi reprehenderit cupiditate perferendis eaque, explicabo blanditiis nemo dolorem aperiam minima deleniti. Tempore, rem, quam? Totam non reiciendis amet, at reprehenderit inventore, adipisci nesciunt itaque dolorum asperiores, ducimus corrupti quam impedit quaerat autem quod officia tempora. Itaque dicta deleniti fugit, laudantium rerum sint consectetur asperiores, quia veritatis dignissimos esse in nesciunt distinctio facere iure facilis voluptatibus placeat voluptate voluptatum expedita animi a veniam nulla ea. Enim aliquid, non. Necessitatibus nam fugiat autem quae qui quam consequatur repudiandae quidem ipsam impedit distinctio, sequi doloribus, quaerat quod ab maxime. Harum facilis sed commodi reprehenderit?<div>(End of Sushi Section) <a href="#sushi"><span>Back to Top</span></a></div></p>
           
          </section>
         </div>
        </div>
    
        <script src="js/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
     <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
       <script src="js/script.js"></script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, Roshan!  It's a little hard to understand what the problem is.  Can you simplify your code so it just includes the parts that are causing trouble?

Comment: Please use punctuation. Your question is very difficult to read.

Comment: sorry for the mistakes.Actually i am not able to find the troubling part.See when the width is from 1200-768px i want the sections declared in code to take 3 parts of screen but whats happening is instead of placing side by side they are stacking one upon another.ALso a scroll bar to scroll in x direction comes but section is not taking place.

Answer (score 0):

There are basic HTML issues. First you need close paragraphs and then start new divs. Secondly, there are fundamental designing issues. Anyways. Here is the updated code for responsive navbar layout ;-).

```css
body {
    background: #F13421;
    font-size: 16px;
    margin: 0;
}

#main-content{
padding-top: 50px;  
}


.chicken, .beef, .sushi {
background-color: #D3D3D3 ; 
    padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar fixed-top  navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Food LLC</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavDropdown" aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavDropdown">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Chicken <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Beef</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Sushi</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
   <!--END OF HEADER-->
    <div id="main-content" class="container">
        <h2 class="text-center mt-4">Our Menu</h2> </div>
<div class="container">
        <div id="tiles" class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4 ">
                <div class="wrapper mt-4"> 
                    <div class="chicken">
                <h3>Chicken</h3>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Repellendus dignissimos aut quasi quibusdam aspernatur possimus officia nulla consectetur velit! At, asperiores dolorem. Et iure assumenda, repudiandae laudantium, voluptatibus ex dignissimos, eum quaerat ducimus cupiditate corporis totam. Illo, alias voluptatem accusamus ut natus consequuntur quis laboriosam doloribus porro vero assumenda quo temporibus quos quam quisquam, libero quod, itaque eius sit ducimus totam iste possimus architecto debitis? Commodi ut minima maiores consequuntur voluptates unde deleniti error vero tempora, eligendi blanditiis, deserunt aliquam nobis porro dolores tenetur amet eius! Aspernatur, vitae. Suscipit, dolores quos doloribus. Velit repudiandae provident a, in ad id aspernatur dolor ratione eos placeat, ex temporibus ipsum eligendi sequi reprehenderit cupiditate perferendis eaque, explicabo blanditiis nemo dolorem aperiam minima deleniti. Tempore, rem, quam? Totam non reiciendis amet, at reprehenderit inventore, adipisci nesciunt itaque dolorum asperiores, ducimus corrupti quam impedit quaerat autem quod officia tempora. Itaque dicta deleniti fugit, laudantium rerum sint consectetur asperiores, quia veritatis dignissimos esse in nesciunt distinctio facere iure facilis voluptatibus placeat voluptate voluptatum expedita animi a veniam nulla ea. Enim aliquid, non. Necessitatibus nam fugiat autem quae qui quam consequatur repudiandae quidem ipsam impedit distinctio, sequi doloribus, quaerat quod ab maxime. Harum facilis sed commodi reprehenderit?</p>
                <div>(End of Chicken Section) <a href="#chicken"><span>Back to Top</span></a></div>
</div>
                </div></div>
           <div class="col-md-4 ">
                <div class="wrapper mt-4"> 
                    <div class="beef">
                <h3>Beef</h3>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Repellendus dignissimos aut quasi quibusdam aspernatur possimus officia nulla consectetur velit! At, asperiores dolorem. Et iure assumenda, repudiandae laudantium, voluptatibus ex dignissimos, eum quaerat ducimus cupiditate corporis totam. Illo, alias voluptatem accusamus ut natus consequuntur quis laboriosam doloribus porro vero assumenda quo temporibus quos quam quisquam, libero quod, itaque eius sit ducimus totam iste possimus architecto debitis? Commodi ut minima maiores consequuntur voluptates unde deleniti error vero tempora, eligendi blanditiis, deserunt aliquam nobis porro dolores tenetur amet eius! Aspernatur, vitae. Suscipit, dolores quos doloribus. Velit repudiandae provident a, in ad id aspernatur dolor ratione eos placeat, ex temporibus ipsum eligendi sequi reprehenderit cupiditate perferendis eaque, explicabo blanditiis nemo dolorem aperiam minima deleniti. Tempore, rem, quam? Totam non reiciendis amet, at reprehenderit inventore, adipisci nesciunt itaque dolorum asperiores, ducimus corrupti quam impedit quaerat autem quod officia tempora. Itaque dicta deleniti fugit, laudantium rerum sint consectetur asperiores, quia veritatis dignissimos esse in nesciunt distinctio facere iure facilis voluptatibus placeat voluptate voluptatum expedita animi a veniam nulla ea. Enim aliquid, non. Necessitatibus nam fugiat autem quae qui quam consequatur repudiandae quidem ipsam impedit distinctio, sequi doloribus, quaerat quod ab maxime. Harum facilis sed commodi reprehenderit?</p>
                <div>(End of Beef Section) <a href="#beef"><span>Back to Top</span></a></div>
</div>
                </div></div>
         <div class="col-md-4 ">
                <div class="wrapper mt-4"> 
                    <div class="sushi">
                <h3>Sushi</h3>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Repellendus dignissimos aut quasi quibusdam aspernatur possimus officia nulla consectetur velit! At, asperiores dolorem. Et iure assumenda, repudiandae laudantium, voluptatibus ex dignissimos, eum quaerat ducimus cupiditate corporis totam. Illo, alias voluptatem accusamus ut natus consequuntur quis laboriosam doloribus porro vero assumenda quo temporibus quos quam quisquam, libero quod, itaque eius sit ducimus totam iste possimus architecto debitis? Commodi ut minima maiores consequuntur voluptates unde deleniti error vero tempora, eligendi blanditiis, deserunt aliquam nobis porro dolores tenetur amet eius! Aspernatur, vitae. Suscipit, dolores quos doloribus. Velit repudiandae provident a, in ad id aspernatur dolor ratione eos placeat, ex temporibus ipsum eligendi sequi reprehenderit cupiditate perferendis eaque, explicabo blanditiis nemo dolorem aperiam minima deleniti. Tempore, rem, quam? Totam non reiciendis amet, at reprehenderit inventore, adipisci nesciunt itaque dolorum asperiores, ducimus corrupti quam impedit quaerat autem quod officia tempora. Itaque dicta deleniti fugit, laudantium rerum sint consectetur asperiores, quia veritatis dignissimos esse in nesciunt distinctio facere iure facilis voluptatibus placeat voluptate voluptatum expedita animi a veniam nulla ea. Enim aliquid, non. Necessitatibus nam fugiat autem quae qui quam consequatur repudiandae quidem ipsam impedit distinctio, sequi doloribus, quaerat quod ab maxime. Harum facilis sed commodi reprehenderit?</p>
                <div>(End of Sushi Section) <a href="#sushi"><span>Back to Top</span></a></div>
</div>
                </div></div>
        </div></div
```

The JS Fiddle Link as follows:

https://jsfiddle.net/hilalrehan/s2kezpgq/

If you want nav bar to be not responsive. Please follow this link

https://jsfiddle.net/hilalrehan/Lwkm1zdc/51/

I believe this will solve your problem.

Comment: bro can you please tell me why in my code the sections are stacking up and not being placed side by side

Comment: To understand this, please refer this post.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22298890/bootstrap-and-html5-section-or-div

Comment: Would appreciate if you vote and provide your feedback regarding my answer. Was it useful or not?